# Regular Expression for login validation

Tags: c#, regex

I need to make a regular expression that checks if the string contains only letters or digits, the first character must be the letter and minimum amount of character is 2 and max 10.

```
string shablon = "/^[a-zA-Z]{2,10}/g";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(shablon);
return myRegex.IsMatch(Login);
```

for login "Igal" its return me a false

any suggestion?

Comment: Drop the `/g` part. This is a flag you should pass to the `Regex` constructor.

Comment: `^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,9}$` first char is letter, followed by 1..9 letters or digits (2..10 in total)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tested for c# and you can use this code :

> ```
>   string shablon = @"^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z1-9]{1,9}";
>             Regex myRegex = new Regex(shablon);
>             var r= myRegex.IsMatch("Igal");
> ```

Comment: The `{1}` is not needed. There is no need to state a repeat count of 1. Having it makes the regular expression harder to understand.

Comment: @AdrianHHH, you're right but this is more clear to understand how it works for beginners

Answer (score 2):

You write your regex with a **slash in the front, and a `/g` at the back**, this is **not part of the actual regex**, these are things some libraries use to *represent regexes*. But the .NET library uses flags passed to the `Regex` constructor.

Furthermore you forgot a dollar (`$`) at the end of the regex. So you can use:

```
csharp> string shablon = "^[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$"; 
csharp> Regex myRegex = new Regex(shablon);  
csharp> myRegex.IsMatch("lgal");      
true
```

> if the string contains only letters or digits, the first character must be the letter and minimum amount of character is 2 and max 10.

Your regex only matches `A-Za-z` two to ten times. So you do not allow digits. You can however rewrite your regex to:

```
csharp> string shablon = "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,9}$"; 
csharp> Regex myRegex = new Regex(shablon);  
csharp> myRegex.IsMatch("lgal");      
true
```

The regex consists out of two parts:

1. `[a-zA-Z]` a character that is a letter; followed by
2. `[a-zA-z0-9]{1,9}` one to nine letters and/or digits.

Comment: Thanks, You save me.